# Running a Macro in Excel as a VBA-Event

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to create a macro that would automatically run before any other macro starts running. I know about the VBA-Events that help to create automatic macros but among the events VBA provides for (as far as I know) there isn't a one that would cover a situation in which some other macro starts running.

The background is that I want to create a macro which would automatically save the active workbook before any other macro starts running. With that accomplished, with the help of another simple macro that would return me to the last saved version of the active workbook, practically some kind of an "undo button" for macros would emerge. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure how many macros you already have that are affected, but I would simply call the run-first macro from all my other macros. Its clean, (very) simple and everybody will understand whats happening. If you already have many other macros , you could automate this with  `Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility`, but that is quite complex and I doubt it would be worth the effort. You can start with this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961711/excel-vba-programmatically-insertline-of-code-to-a-specific-sub-macro-in-a-wor)